# How do I use PHP's preg_match to validate strings?

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match

Please tell me how to use the various symbols used for expression matching in `preg_match` function of PHP.

Besides basic information, please give example for checking a valid e-mail address and a string that should not contain / : ; { } * &

Answer (score 2):

Simple example.. Verifying $var which is a string verifying and checking for (a to z AND A to Z) characters.

```
<?php
$var = 'hello';
if (ereg("[a-zA-Z]", $var)) {
  echo 'it was typed correctly';
} else {
  echo 'it was not typed correctly';
}
?>
```

more regular expressions syntax exemples: http://www.regexlib.com/

EDIT:

```
if (ereg("^([0-9,a-z,A-Z]+)([.,_]([0-9,a-z,A-Z]+))*[@]([0-9,a-z,A-Z]+)([.,_,-]([0-9,a-z,A-Z]+))*[.]([0-9,a-z,A-Z]){2}([0-9,a-z,A-Z])?$", $email)) {

  echo 'email ok';

} else {

  echo 'email not ok';

}
```

Regards.

Comment: I recommend using regular expressions(regex) for string/email validation..
(ereg in Php)
The example just up i use it for 2 years.. Never let me down.

Sure there yes a smaller regex expression.. But i like to keep the ones i know it works well.

Comment: Anyone just starting out with regexes in PHP should use the preg suite, not ereg.  preg is based on the PCRE library, and it's one of the most powerful, feature-rich flavors in existence.  ereg, based on the POSIX standard, uses a different syntax and is much less powerful; it's really only supported for historical reasons.

Comment: From the PHP manual page on ereg. ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php )
"Warning
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged."

Answer (score 1):

[Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) recently had an article on his [coding horror blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) about regular expressions. Check out "[Regular Expressions for Regular Programmers](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001274.html)".

Comment: nice article
pretty hilarious i must say

Answer (score 0):

To check for a valid mail you can either use build in functionality ([filter_var()/FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL](https://www.php.net/filter_var)) or use nice ready to use libraries which are compliant to the current RFC. [PHP : Parsing Email Adresses in PHP](http://www.iamcal.com/publish/articles/php/parsing_email). For examples on [preg_match()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) you can go to the php website and a full list regular expression options is available on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). To learn about Regex I recommend "[The Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/)".

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is about PHP, but my purpose is to illustrate the intricacies of email address validation: To check if an email address conforms to [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822), you can use the Perl module [Email::Address](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email::Address). Do take a look at the source of that module as well as the RFC.

Answer (score 0):

If I give $var = 'hello87%^$' also returning "it was typed correctly";